# Using Shared Preferences Package to store user's favorite items, but it does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Here is where user selects an item as favorite:

```
class ItemCard extends StatefulWidget {
    ValueKey key;
  ItemCard(this.key) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<ItemCard> createState() => _ItemCardState();
}

class _ItemCardState extends State<ItemCard> {
  late SharedPreferences pref;
  List<String> favs = [];
  getPref() async {
    pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      favs = pref.getStringList('favorited') ?? [];
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
   
    getPref();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final item = Provider.of<Item>(context, listen: false);
    bool isFav = favs.any((element) => element == item.id);
    if (isFav && item.isFavorite == false) {
      item.toggleFavoriteStatus();
    }
 
    return Directionality(
          ///some code
                Consumer<Item>(
                  builder: (ctx, item, child) => InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      List<String> favoritedItems = [];
                      favoritedItems
                          .addAll(pref.getStringList('favorited') ?? []);
                      if (isFav == true) {
                        favoritedItems
                            .removeWhere((element) => element == item.id);
                        pref.setStringList(
                            'favorited', [...favoritedItems, item.id as String]);
                        print('item.id: ${item.id}');
                      }
                      item.toggleFavoriteStatus();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.white60,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(item.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white,),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          
    );
  }
}
```

It is the code for Favorite Items Screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../provider/items.dart';
import '../widget/itemCard.dart';

class FavoritesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FavoritesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/Favorites';
  @override
  _FavoritesScreenState createState() => _FavoritesScreenState();
}

class _FavoritesScreenState extends State<FavoritesScreen> {
  late SharedPreferences pref;
  List<String> favoriteItemsId = [];
  getPref() async {
    pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      favoriteItemsId = pref.getStringList('favorited') ?? [];
      print("/////////////////////ssssssssssssdddddddddddddsssssssgffgg" +
          pref.getStringList('favorited').toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    
    getPref();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final favoriteItems = Provider.of<Items>(context).items;
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: favoriteItemsId.isEmpty
            ? const Center(
                child: Text('Favorites!'),
              )
            : GridView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                  bool fav = favoriteItemsId
                      .any((element) => element == favoriteItems[index].id);
                  return fav
                      ? ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                          value: favoriteItems[index],
                          child: ItemCard(
                            ValueKey(favoriteItems[index].id),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container();
                },
                itemCount: favoriteItems.length,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the `Item` class:

```
class Item with ChangeNotifier {
  final String? title;
  final String? author;
  final String? id;
  final String? category;
  final String? content;
  final String? startColor;
  final String? endColor;
  bool isFavorite;
  Item({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.author,

    @required this.id,
    @required this.category,
    @required this.content,
    @required this.startColor,
    @required this.endColor,
    this.isFavorite = false,

  });
  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new common preference class like this and use it as per your needs.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Preferences preferences = Preferences();

var title = "Preferences";

class Preferences {

  static Preferences? _instance;

  Preferences._() {}

  factory Preferences() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = new Preferences._();
    }
    // since you are sure you will return non-null value, add '!' operator
    return _instance!;
  }

  SharedPreferences? _prefs;

  Future<SharedPreferences> get prefs async {
    if (_prefs != null) return _prefs!;

    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return _prefs!;
  }


  Future<bool> saveBool(String key, bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setBool(key, value);
  }

  Future<bool> getBool(String key, bool defValue) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool(key) ?? defValue;
  }


  Future<bool> saveString(String key, String value) async {
    final pref = await prefs;
    return pref.setString(key, value);
    ///////////// OR
    //SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //return  prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

  Future<String> getString(String key, String defValue) async {
    final pref = await prefs;
    return pref.getString(key) ?? defValue;
    ///////////// OR
    //SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //return prefs.getString(key) ?? defValue;
  }

  Future<bool> saveJson(String key, dynamic value) async {
    final pref = await prefs;
    return pref.setString(key, json.encode(value.toJson()));
  }

  Future<dynamic> getJson(String key, dynamic defValue) async {
    final pref = await prefs;
    return json.decode(pref.getString(key)!) ?? defValue;
  }

  Future<bool> saveInt(String key, int value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setInt(key, value);
  }

  Future<int> getInt(String key, int value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getInt(key) ?? value;
  }

  Future<bool> saveDouble(String key, double value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setDouble(key, value);
  }

  Future<double> getDouble(String key, double value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getDouble(key) ?? value;
  }

  Future<bool> saveStringList(String key, List<String> value) async {
    final pref = await prefs;
    return pref.setStringList(key, value);
  }

  Future<List<String>> getStringList(String key, List<String> value) async {
    final pref = await prefs;
    return pref.getStringList(key) ?? value;
  }

  Future<bool> setMap(String tag, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sharedPreferences.setString(tag, jsonEncode(data));
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getMap(String tag) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return jsonDecode(sharedPreferences.getString(tag) ?? '{}');
  }

  Future<bool> setList(String tag, List<dynamic> data) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sharedPreferences.setString(tag, jsonEncode(data));
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> getList(String tag) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return jsonDecode(sharedPreferences.getString(tag) ?? '[]');
  }

  Future clearPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear();
  }

  Future removeValues(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how should I use it?

Comment: just the same as  before?

Comment: Would you please help me with this issue if I share my entire code with you on GitHub?

Comment: Yes, Sure. I am happy to help you. Send me your github code link.

Comment: https://github.com/Morteza100-tech/database-app Here is the code. My friend helped to solve the problem somehow, but it still has some problems. You can check and tell me how to solve the remaining problems. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[setStringList()](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/setStringList.html) is a future. You should await it as follow :

```
await pref.setStringList('favorited', [...favoritedItems, item.id as String]);
```