# How to save a list locally to a database with shared preferences in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

How can I  save a list locally to a database with shared preferences in flutter .
for example :- I have list List notification = []; How can I save this list locally with shared preferences?

Comment: Refer to this solution This will solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971181/18090919

Answer (score 0):

The plugin itself already has a method for storing `List<String>`, it's called [setStringList](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/setStringList.html).

If you have some other type of data to store, you simply have to convert them in `String` and have a function to convert them back in your data type.

The other question linked in the comments is just a collection of convenience methods to store different data types, but it's nothing you can't write on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
const  _notificationListKey='notificationList';
Future<void> notificationInLocalStorage( List notificationList ) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await Future.wait([
  prefs.setString(_notificationListKey,json.encode( notificationList)),
]);
}
```