# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'. Flutter JSON

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, decode

I've made this class and I encoded it in JSON but when I try to retrieve data it is Showing me that **List dynamic** is not a subtype of **List String**

I saved the data for favouriteMeals, that is a List
here,

```
void saveData() {
    List<String> spList =
        _favouriteMeals.map((e) => jsonEncode(e.toMap())).toList();
    sharedPreferences.setStringList('favMeals', spList);
    print(spList);
  }
```

And now when I'm trying to load my data it is showing me this error. Can anyone please help me?

```
    void loadData() {
        List<String> spList = sharedPreferences.getStringList('favMeals');
        //print(spList);
        _favouriteMeals = spList.map((e) => Meal.fromMap(json.decode(e))).toList();
        print(_favouriteMeals[0].id);
        

setState(() {});
  }
```

> This is meal class.

```
class Meal {
      final String id;
      final List<String> categories;
      final String title;
      final String imageUrl;
      final List<String> ingredients;
      final List<String> steps;
      final int duration;
      final Complexity complexity;
      final Affordability affordability;
      final bool isGlutenFree;
      final bool isLactoseFree;
      final bool isVegan;
      final bool isVegetarian;
    
      const Meal(
          {@required this.id,
          @required this.categories,
          @required this.title,
          @required this.imageUrl,
          @required this.ingredients,
          @required this.steps,
          @required this.duration,
          @required this.complexity,
          @required this.affordability,
          @required this.isGlutenFree,
          @required this.isLactoseFree,
          @required this.isVegan,
          @required this.isVegetarian});
      Meal.fromMap(Map map)
          : this.id = map['id'],
            this.categories = map['categories'],
            this.title = map['title'],
            this.imageUrl = map['imageUrl'],
            this.ingredients = map['ingredients'],
            this.steps = map['steps'],
            this.duration = map['duration'],
            this.complexity = Complexity.values.elementAt(map['complexity']),
            this.affordability =
                Affordability.values.elementAt(map['affordability']),
            this.isGlutenFree = map['isGlutenFree'],
            this.isLactoseFree = map['isLactoseFree'],
            this.isVegan = map['isVegan'],
            this.isVegetarian = map['isVegetarian'];
      Map toMap() {
        return {
          'id': this.id,
          'categories': this.categories,
          'title': this.title,
          'imageUrl': this.imageUrl,
          'ingredients': this.ingredients,
          'steps': this.steps,
          'duration': this.duration,
          'complexity': this.complexity.index,
          'affordability': this.affordability.index,
          'isGlutenFree': this.isGlutenFree,
          'isLactoseFree': this.isLactoseFree,
          'isVegan': this.isVegan,
          'isVegetarian': this.isVegetarian,
        };
      }
```

}

Comment: Please share error message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971181/18090919
try to save and get your list using this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
_favouriteMeals = spList.map((e) => Meal.fromMap(Map.from(jsonDecode(e)))).toList();
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same thing nothing changed

Comment: Saving the list works fine, yes?

Comment: yea saving was working fine, but the problem was in loading

Comment: When you print spList after `        List<String> spList = sharedPreferences.getStringList('favMeals');
` does it work?

Comment: yes that works fine